# Redirect from subfolder to subdomain

Tags: subdomain, redirect

This should be simple right? I've tried a few solutions with no results...

```
How do I redirect:  

http://www.domainname.com/subdomain   and    http://www.domainname.com/subdomain/    

to: 

htt://subdomain/domainname.com   and   htt://subdomain/domainname.com/
```

~

What code should I use, and do I place it in .htaccess of the domainname.com root folder?

or in the subdomain folder?

Thanks so much!

JD

Answer (score 1):

I'm presumming a typo in your request and that you wish to redirect:

http://www.domainname.com/subdomain ---->   http://subdomain.domainname.com

If you are using apache, I'd use the following directive in the httpd.conf file:

```
Redirect /subdomain http://subdomain.domainname.com
```

Comment: I'm using Apache. what is the httpd.conf file? Wouldn't I be adding that code to my .htaccess file? Would this go in the subdomain folder then or the domainname.com root folder? Thanks!

Comment: I placed your code in the .htaccess file in the subdomain folder and got the following error: 

Common reasons for this error are:

    * Incorrect file/directory permissions: Above 755.

      In order files to be processed by the webserver, their permissions have to be equal or below 755. You can update file permissions with a FTP client or through cPanel's File Manager.
    * Incorrect Apache directives inside .htaccess file.

      Make sure you have not specified unsupported directives inside the local .htaccess file. Such include PHP settings and Apache module settings.

Comment: I checked my error log ---- Invalid command 're', perhaps mis-spelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration ---

Comment: Here is the URI that describes the directive:

    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

And if you're using IIS, set up redirects in the site properties in the IIS management snapin.